# How to make my old front end and new front end available at the same time with same app domain?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, azure, frontend, saas

We wrote a SAAS application ([www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com)) 5 years back and wrote our frontend in Angularjs, Now we are looking to modernize the application and planning to write in Reactjs. I am analyzing the following approaches:

1. Create a new front end on a different domain ([www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)) and let my Saas users know the new URL and give them some notice that we will down the old URL in some time.
2. Create a new front end on the same domain ([www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com)) and provide a toggle button and let users choose whatever they want to.

The second approach looks more promising to me but I am not sure how to deploy my front end which uses a different technology and still can be deployed on the same app domain. Can someone put some light on that Is it achievable?

The current application is deployed on Azure app service with frontend and APIS but now we are planning to migrate our application from Monolith to Microservices. Frontend we are planning to deploy on CDN and container-based services. The old front end will keep using the old Azure App Services API but the new front end will consume the new microservices.

Comment: Use subdomains, the toggle button can redirect to new the site and the old site

Comment: In the case of subdomain if my route is:  www.abcd.com then the new URL should be www.new.abcd.com and eventually, I will have to down my old HTML content to host the new one on the original URL

Comment: subdomains can be pointed at different machines hosting entirely different technologies

Comment: I was also thinking if we can put some gateway and write the URL inbound and outbound rules to decide which server will serve my HTML. Similar to it serve the Backend.